# Python turn hard code into loop that iterates through every element

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was wondering how I would turn my hardcoding section into a loop? I have a very long array that would require me to iterate through every element, drop it, and apply the functions. but hard coding would take forever. ie. apply functions with everything but the first element then append to list, apply functions with everything but the second element then append to list, and so on

```
x1 = np.array([1,2,4,6])
y1 = np.array([2,4,6,3])
x2 = np.array([2,4,2,7])
y2 = np.array([2,5,3,4])
x3 = np.array([3,5,4,3])
y3 = np.array([2,6,1,2])
x4 = np.array([6,6,4,7])
y4 = np.array([8,9,8,4])

xs = np.array([x1,x2,x3,x4])
ys = np.array([y1,y2,y3,x4])

linear_r2 = []
quadratic_r2 = []

def linear_func(x, a, b):
    return (a * x) + b

def fit_r2(ydata, yfit):
    residuals = ydata - yfit 
    ss_res = np.sum(residuals**2)
    ss_tot = np.sum((ydata - np.mean(ydata))**2)
    r2 = 1 - (ss_res / ss_tot)
    return r2

#hardcoding
xs_1 = np.delete(xs,0,axis = 1) #deletes 0th element for all arrays
ys_1 = np.delete(ys,0,axis = 1) #deletes 0th element for all arrays
xdata = xs_1[0,:]
ydata = ys_1[0,:]
popt, _ = curve_fit(linear_func, xdata, ydata)
yfit = linear_func(xdata, *popt)
linear_1 = fit_r2(ydata,yfit)
linear_r2.append(linear_1)

xs_2 = np.delete(xs,1,axis = 1) ##deletes 1st element for all arrays
ys_2 = np.delete(ys,1,axis = 1)
xdata = xs_2[0,:]
ydata = ys_2[0,:]
popt, _ = curve_fit(linear_func, xdata, ydata)
yfit = linear_func(xdata, *popt)
linear_2 = fit_r2(ydata,yfit)
linear_r2.append(linear_2)

#and so on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for ind in range(xs.shape[1]):
    xs_1 = np.delete(xs,ind,axis = 1) #deletes i-th element for all arrays
    ys_1 = np.delete(ys,ind,axis = 1) #deletes i-th element for all arrays
```

the rest is the same (all under the loop):

```
xdata = xs_1[0,:]
ydata = ys_1[0,:]
popt, _ = curve_fit(linear_func, xdata, ydata)
yfit = linear_func(xdata, *popt)
linear_1 = fit_r2(ydata,yfit)
linear_r2.append(linear_1)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for replying, this works well. But it doesn't seem to loop through the last element? I'm expecting to have 4 outputs in the list, but it only has 3

Comment: I've got it, just needed to remove the " - 1". Thank you!

Comment: Thx for the update, I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to delete at all. Try this:

```
for i in range(min(len(xs), len(ys))):
    xdata = xs_1[i,:]
    ydata = ys_1[i,:]
    popt, _ = curve_fit(linear_func, xdata, ydata)
    yfit = linear_func(xdata, *popt)
    linear_1 = fit_r2(ydata,yfit)
    linear_r2.append(linear_1)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! So It seems like it worked with 4 integers for each array, but I added a 5th and 6th integer for each of the np arrays, but there only seems to have for 4 outputs?

Comment: The loop runs N times, where N is the smaller of [length of xs, length of ys]. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh i see, so its looping four times because xs and ys has 4 variables. But I need to loop through every element in x1,y1,x2,y2. ie.  if the arrays have 6 elements vs 4 elements from my example: x1 = np.array([1,2,4,6,4,5])
y1 = np.array([2,4,6,3,2,3])
x2 = np.array([2,4,2,7,4,1])
y2 = np.array([2,5,3,4,4,2])
x3 = np.array([3,5,4,3,1,4])
y3 = np.array([2,6,1,2,4,1])
x4 = np.array([6,6,4,7,4,2])
y4 = np.array([8,9,8,4,5,2])

xs = np.array([x1,x2,x3,x4])
ys = np.array([y1,y2,y3,x4])